# Passing multiline string from DB into javascript variable

Tags: javascript, mysql, jsp, servlets

firstly, I must apologize for bad english, it's not my main language.

I'm using MySQL DB. So, I have a multiline string inside a DB. I read it in servlet and pass in jsp. In jsp I'm using something like this:

```
<script>
var foo = {
... 
title: "<c:out value="${myMultilineString}"/>",
... 
}
</script>
```

but is doesn't works.

I tried to change source string like this:

1)"line1

line2"
on page it look like this:

title:"line1

line2" this is an error

2)"line1\nline2" no errors, but string isn't multiline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The html tag for changing line is **< br />**.

So try replacing your **\n** from database with **< br />** and then assign it to **tittle**

Comment: the DB changes < br /> to &lt;br/&gt;

I also tried to store string like this:

line1" + 
"line2

but DB replacing '"' to it's code,

can you tell me how to "fix" it?

Comment: ok, replace the &lt;br/&gt;  with <br/> and then assign it to tittle

Comment: I write `title: "<c:out value="${MyMultilineString}"/>".split('&lt;br/&gt;').join('<br/>')` and it worked! Thanks for help :)